# What's the best way to get updated Character by moving a given Integer

Tags: swift, character, ascii

Swift character is so hard to manipulate..
I have a simple request:
For a given string, I'd like to encode it with a "moving integer" for all the alphabetical digits.

For example: "abc", move 1: would become "bcd"; "ABC", move 1 -> "BCD".
One thing to note is, if after moving, the range it larger than "z" or "Z", it should loop back and calculate from "a" or "A" again. e.g "XYZ", move 1 -> "YZA"

This would be very easy to do in Java. But could anyone show me what would be the cleanest way to do it swift?

I've done something like:

```
let arr: [Character] = Array(s)
for i in arr {
    let curAsciiValue = i.asciiValue!
    var updatedVal = (curAsciiValue + UInt8(withRotationFactor))
    if i >= "A" && i <= "Z" {
        newAsciiVal = 65
        updatedVal = updatedVal - 65 >= 26 ? 65 + (updatedVal - 65) % 26 : updatedVal         
    } else if i >= "a" && i <= "z" {
        newAsciiVal  = 97
        updatedVal = updatedVal - 97 >= 26 ? 97 + (updatedVal - 97) % 26 : updatedVal
    }
}
```

What should be best way to do this?

Comment: isLetter won't match only alphabet letters like a...z and A...Z. It will match all kind of letters like `ç` as well

Comment: any way to only match a-z?

Comment: sure `"a"..."z" ~= char || "A"..."Z" ~= char`

Comment: ok updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Better to bring all your logic together extending the `Character` type:

```
extension Character {
    var isAlphabet: Bool { isLowercaseAlphabet || isUppercaseAlphabet }
    var isLowercaseAlphabet: Bool { "a"..."z" ~= self }
    var isUppercaseAlphabet: Bool { "A"..."Z" ~= self }
    func rotateAlphabetLetter(_ factor: Int) -> Self? {
        precondition(factor > 0, "rotation must be positive")
        guard let asciiValue = asciiValue, isAlphabet else { return nil }
        let addition = asciiValue + UInt8(factor % 26)
        return .init(UnicodeScalar(addition > (isLowercaseAlphabet ? 122 : 90) ? addition - 26 : addition))
    }
}
```

---

```
Character("a").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // "c"
Character("A").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // "C"
Character("j").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // "l"
Character("J").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // "L"
Character("z").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // "b"
Character("Z").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // "B"
Character("ç").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // nil
Character("Ç").rotateAlphabetLetter(2)  // nil
```

Expanding on that you can map your string elements using `compactMap`:

```
let string = "XYZ"
let rotatedAlphabetLetters = string.compactMap { $0.rotateAlphabetLetter(2) }  // ["Z", "A", "B"]
```

---

And to convert the sequence of characters back to string:

```
extension Sequence where Element == Character {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

---

```
let result = rotatedAlphabetLetters.string  // "ZAB"
```

---

or simply in one liner:

```
let result = "XYZ".compactMap { $0.rotateAlphabetLetter(2) }.string  // "ZAB"
```